# DDMS Screenshot tool copy does not work on Linux

Tags: android, linux, screenshot, ddms

Using DDMS via Eclipse or through Monitor, it will take the screenshot, but when you copy to clipboard. You can't do anything with it. Gimp, Inkscape, LibreOffice don't recognise what is in the clipboard. 
The save option is not that good because the quality it uses to save the png is awful. This makes it difficult to create good quality screenshots for your app. Because of the high resolution of devices the window of the captured screen goes outside the bounds of the desktop/workspace so you can't use a take a screenshot of that window.

Is there another trick to getting around this, like being able to change quality setting ddms saves images? or using adb shell to take screenshots. Is there a screen capture tool in Linux that can take screenshots across workspaces.

ATM I am taking two screenshot one for each workscape the window is on and then using GIMP to line up the images, this takes time, and it is frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can take screen shot using `adb shell` as

`adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/img.png`

It will be in your sdcard of emulator  you can push it out to system ...

I think the above code works from `ICS` .

Comment: it doesn't seem to give you control over the quality. The quality is a little better than the DDMS.

Comment: Thats what you asked , better quality than ddms